# Android AdMob Phonegap Not Working

Tags: android, android-layout, cordova, admob

Can anyone help me, I am trying to implement admob in android since last two days, but getting following error messages -

> 08-08 19:05:33.362: W/webcore(3228): Can't get the viewWidth after the
>   first layout 08-08 19:10:51.632: W/dalvikvm(3328): VFY: unable to
>   resolve direct method 3204: Landroid/webkit/WebView;.
>   (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;IZ)V 08-08
>   19:10:51.662: I/webclipboard(3328): clipservice:
>   android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@40534500 08-08 19:10:52.142:
>   I/CordovaLog(3328): Changing log level to DEBUG(3) 08-08 19:10:52.142:
>   I/CordovaLog(3328): Found preference for useBrowserHistory=false 08-08
>   19:10:52.142: D/CordovaLog(3328): Found preference for
>   useBrowserHistory=false 08-08 19:10:52.152: E/dalvikvm(3328): Could
>   not find class 'android.webkit.WebResourceResponse', referenced from
>   method
>   org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebViewClient.generateWebResourceResponse
>   08-08 19:10:52.152: W/dalvikvm(3328): VFY: unable to resolve
>   new-instance 467 (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;) in
>   Lorg/apache/cordova/CordovaWebViewClient; 08-08 19:10:52.152:
>   W/dalvikvm(3328): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature
>   (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;) 08-08 19:10:52.182:
>   W/dalvikvm(3328): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature
>   (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;) 08-08 19:10:52.182:
>   W/dalvikvm(3328): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature
>   (Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;) 08-08 19:10:52.182:
>   W/dalvikvm(3328): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3225:
>   Landroid/webkit/WebViewClient;.shouldInterceptRequest
>   (Landroid/webkit/WebView;Ljava/lang/String;)Landroid/webkit/WebResourceResponse;
>   08-08 19:10:52.182: D/DroidGap(3328): DroidGap.init() 08-08
>   19:10:52.192: D/CordovaWebView(3328): >>>
>   loadUrl(file:///android_asset/www/index.html) 08-08 19:10:52.192:
>   D/PluginManager(3328): init() 08-08 19:10:52.212:
>   D/CordovaWebView(3328): >>> loadUrlNow() 08-08 19:10:52.272:
>   E/Ads(3328): Could not find com.google.ads.AdActivity, please make
>   sure it is registered in AndroidManifest.xml. 08-08 19:10:52.272:
>   E/Ads(3328): You must have AdActivity declared in AndroidManifest.xml
>   with configChanges. 08-08 19:10:52.282: I/webclipboard(3328):
>   clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@405512e0 08-08
>   19:10:52.332: I/webclipboard(3328): clipservice:
>   android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@405512e0 08-08 19:10:52.902:
>   D/AndroidRuntime(3328): Shutting down VM 08-08 19:10:52.902:
>   W/dalvikvm(3328): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception
>   (group=0x40018578) 08-08 19:10:52.902: E/AndroidRuntime(3328): FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main 08-08 19:10:52.902: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.ApplicationNexus.Albania/com.ApplicationNexus.Albania.Albania}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 08-08 19:10:52.902:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3328):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
>   08-08 19:10:52.902: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
>   08-08 19:10:52.902: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117) 08-08
>   19:10:52.902: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
>   08-08 19:10:52.902: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 08-08
>   19:10:52.902: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130) 08-08 19:10:52.902:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3328):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687) 08-08
>   19:10:52.902: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 08-08
>   19:10:52.902: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507) 08-08 19:10:52.902:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3328):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
>   08-08 19:10:52.902: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625) 08-08
>   19:10:52.902: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 08-08 19:10:52.902:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(3328): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   08-08 19:10:52.902: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):   at
>   com.ApplicationNexus.Albania.Albania.onCreate(Albania.java:22) 08-08
>   19:10:52.902: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
>   08-08 19:10:52.902: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
>   08-08 19:10:52.902: E/AndroidRuntime(3328):   ... 11 more

```
Following is the code of my main java file -


    import org.apache.cordova.*;
    import com.google.ads.*;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
    import android.widget.*;

    public class Albania extends DroidGap {
        private AdView adView;


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
            super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 70000);
            adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a1502224a0ab1f8");
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adView);
            layout.addView(adView);
            adView.loadAd(new AdRequest()); }
```

here is my activity_appname.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        tools:context=".Albania" />


    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, S567041ba118d"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

here is my android manifest.xml file

```
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Albania"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_albania" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|orientation|keyboard|screenSize|uiMode|screenLayout|locale"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> 
    <activity
        android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
 android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />         
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

From [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10672334/could-not-find-com-google-ads-adactivity-must-have-adactivity-declared-in-the-ma), make sure you have in your manifest xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to specify an `AdView` in XML and in code.  Just put `ads:adUnitId="a1502224a0ab1f8"` into the `com.google.ads.AdView` in your XML, and you can remove the following Adview code:

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a1502224a0ab1f8");
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adView);
layout.addView(adView);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

EDIT:

Cordova has you load a url and abstracts the way you set your view.  You'll have to manually get the Cordova WebView's parent, and add an AdView to the parentView.  The code might look something like this:

```
adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a1502224a0ab1f8");
// Get the parent of the cordova webview. May be able to do something like: this.webView.getParent();
parentView.addView(adView);
adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

Comment: You mean to say I have to do this in my xml file -

`code`  <com.google.ads.AdView 
                         ads:adUnitId="a1502224a0ab1f8" 
                         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                         ads:adSize="BANNER"
                         ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR,S567041ba118d"
                         ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/> `code`

I didn't understand this "remove the Adview code".

Comment: correct - I've updated my answer to show you what Java code you'll no longer need.

Comment: Thank You very much for replying, that removed all errors. However, test ads are not getting displayed on my device. I have removed that code from the Java file and modified the xml file like this - 

`code`
     <com.google.ads.AdView ads:adUnitId="a1502224a0ab1f8"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
      ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR,S567041ba118d,0A3AA88D17028026"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
`code`

Comment: The test device ID that the AdMob SDK looks for is a hashed ID, so those you've provided aren't valid.  Try running your app on device again, and after you've made an ad request, check the logcat for a message like `To get test ads on device, use adRequest.addTestDevice("YOUR_32_HEX_DIGIT_HASHED_DEVICE_ID")`.  Then try putting that device ID into your testDevices list, and it should work.

Comment: I tried everything and also published my app to Google Play Store, but it is still not showing the Admob ads. Here is the Google Play URL -

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ApplicationNexus.Albania

Comment: I downloaded your app.  It's not making an ad request. You have an xml file, but you're not setting the content view as that xml file, so it's not being used.  Instead, I would try to grab the parent of the webView that the DroidGap class holds and add an AdView to the parentView (using the java code you originally had).  I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks Eric, I added following code in my main java file   
  AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.ad);  
  adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a1502224a0ab1f8");  
  adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());  
  
  And Getting this in logcat file  
  08-16 19:03:30.696: I/Ads(6763): Received ad url: <url:   "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?......... 

Admob account is also showing this status "your site is currently sending ad requests to adMob. But ad not appearing on the app, how much time it takes?

Comment: What is R.id.ad?  This isn't in your original XML file.  Also remember that creating an XML file won't work since super.loadUrl() is essentially creating the contentView for you under the hood.  You'll need to find the WebView object inside of DroidGap, get it's parent, and ad the adView as a child element of the WebView's parent.

Comment: Actually in my xml, I changed my id to android:id="@+id/ad", it was prevously adView. This is my first Cordova Android app, I don't have much idea about JAVA programming. How can I do this - find WebView Object inside of DroidGap, get it's parent, and ad the adView as a child element of the WebView's parent. Sorry for asking that, but what should I search?